# How to get lag value without using the lag function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have

```
id   minutes
1     2:40:00 
1     3:40:00
1     5:40:00
2     6:40:00
2     7:40:00
2     8:40:00
```

With the lag function

> SELECT id, minutes as earlier_time, lag(minutes) OVER(PARTITION BY id
>   ORDER BY id, minutes) as later_time FROM table1

I get

```
   id   earlier_time 
    1     2:40:00    3:40:00
    1     3:40:00    5:40:00
    1     5:40:00    NULL
    2     6:40:00    7:40:00
    2     7:40:00    8:40:00
    2     8:40:00    NULL
```

Is there a way to do that without the lag function?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `LAG` function until MySQL 8.0.

Comment: yeah thats's why I need a way to do that without the LAG function... @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar That question is different. It doesn't return the previous value.

Comment: I've added several more. All you have to do is search SO for `[mysql] lag function`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! @Barmar

Comment: @rose Concider to solve that issue in application language. 3 of the 4 linked answers are using an unreliable "hack".